# Errors were encountered while processing: systemd

Tags: php, mysql, debian

I am trying to install some package but getting this error evry time how I can fix it? Does`nt metter if I want to install this or other package

```
apt-get install mysql-server php5.6-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.5.9999+default).
The following NEW packages will be installed:
php5.6-common php5.6-mysql
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 398 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 872 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4924 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://packages.sury.org/php jessie/main amd64 php5.6-common amd64 5.6.36-1+0~20180505045733.13+jessie~1.gbp9b5cab [730 kB]
Get:2 https://packages.sury.org/php jessie/main amd64 php5.6-mysql amd64 5.6.36-1+0~20180505045733.13+jessie~1.gbp9b5cab [142 kB]
Fetched 872 kB in 0s (1047 kB/s)
Setting up systemd (232-25+deb9u3) ...
addgroup: The group `systemd-journal' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
adduser: The user `systemd-timesync' already exists. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Check out this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295123/warning-because-addgroup-tries-to-create-an-already-existing-user-group

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt install --reinstall systemd`